# PHP Sending 10 concurrent request to api?

Tags: php

I have a table which contain 1lack records,  so i need to send all the records to api with in 5 seconds and the api accept only 10 record per request. and no problem i can increase time range from 5 to 25seconds.

So how can i make concurrent 10 request?

Example

```
100k records
$records_array // accepting 10 records per connection.
function sendCamp($records_array){
    connectionToServer();
    for($i = 0; $i<recordslength; $i++){
          callSMS($records_array[$i]);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to decypher question.

Comment: I need php logic, to split and then send the table records.

Comment: one of the php loop functions? can you show some code?

Comment: "1lack" is probably "1 lakh" = 100,000. Indian numbering system.

Comment: Not indain, asian numbering system.

Answer (score 1):

You can split records into groups of 10 and then use [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to send them in parallel. That should considerably decrease execution time.